# Multiple windows and TextField

Tags: python, kivy, screen, kivymd

I want to make an Android app to scan QR codes.
I already have 2 windows (ScreenManager) one of them is like 'main menu' with button 'scan' and MDTextField.
When i click on 'scan' button, secound window was run and it works fine. But i dont know how to send readed code co MDTextField on 'main menu'.

```
<ProfileWindow>:
name: 'secound'
MDBoxLayout:
 orientation: 'vertical'
 ZBarCam:
  id: qrcodecam
 MDLabel:
  adaptive_height: True
  md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
  text: ''.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in qrcodecam.symbols])
```

Another problem is, when i want to set value on MDTextField, i cant do that. I think problem is on that windows.I use

```
self.root.ids.date_label.text = 'Cancel'
```

but recive an error after on_press

```
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: for me - its a minimal

Comment: Please read the linked text.